# How to modify and enumerate XML tags in python

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup, elementtree

I have realized that in a corpus XML file many sentences are missing the **sentence ID** which are important to navigate through them. I would like now to iterate through all `<sentence/>` tags and add an attribute with an enumerating value such as: `<sentence id="1">`, and the next `<sentence id="2">` and so on.

In BeautifulSoup one can add attributes: `soup.find('sentence')['id'] = '1'`
that returns `<sentence id="1">`in the tree.

Now, how can I increment that number continously? (Suggestions for Elementtree are also very welcome)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `enumerate` on the result of `find_all`, like this:

```
items = soup.find_all('sentence')
for index,items in enumerate(items):
    items['id'] = str(index)
```

By default, `enumerate` starts indexing with `0`. As pointed out by Keyur Potdat, you can use `enumerate(items,1)` to set the first `id` to `1`, or any other starting value (see also https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#enumerate).

Comment: Or, simply `enumerate(sentences, 1)`

Comment: Thanks! One question: I get "NameError: name 'sentence' is not defined"

Comment: @PaulKremershof: ack – I tested on one of my own XML files, which had different elements & id designations, so I had to re-write the working code to use yours. The *array* is `items` (and can be anything), the *element* is `sentence` (and must match your XML). [Changed variables for clarity.]

Comment: @KeyurPotdar: an argument of `enumerate` which I hadn't seen before – thanks!